# Trouble joining and filtering data in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am having trouble performing this query. First, the .schema:

```
CREATE TABLE cities (name text, state text);
CREATE TABLE weather (city text, year int, warm_month text, cold_month text, average_high int);
```

I have a table of city name / state values, and then a weather table with the columns listed above. I need my query to find the mean of the average high temperatures for all of the cities within a state.

My query is as follows:

```
select city, avg(average_high) from weather
  ...> inner join cities
  ...> on name = city
  ...> group by state;
```

This actually displays the correct average for each state, but it displays a city name rather than the state name. I know that I ask for city in my select statement, and I never select state anywhere... I guess I need an additional select statement but I don't know the syntax.

Comment: If you've got an answer to your question, feel encouraged to add it **as an answer**.  Editing it into your question introduces more noise for others that are looking for this similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

What about

select state, avg(average_high)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks maxymoo - I solved it yesterday but your solution is correct. The corrected query is:

```
 select state, avg(average_high) from weather
        inner join cities
        on name = city
        group by state;
```

For some reason I thought that I couldn't ask for `state`, because it isn't in the `weather` table. Since I inner join `cities` on the next line of the query, I can!